# Question regarding multivariable limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

we recently started learning about multivariable limits in class. I have to find the following limit:
[image]

Here is my working so far. I'm stuck at this point. How do I proceed? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We are interested in investigating if the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)} \frac{u^2+v^2+2(u+v)}{|u|+|v|}$$

If $u=v$, then the problem reduces to $\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{2u^2+4u}{2|u|}=\lim_{u \to 0}\operatorname{sign}(u)(u+2)$

of which the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

set $$y=tx$$ in your term, then you will get
$$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{|x-1|}=\pm (x+1)$$ (for $t=1$) thus the Limit doesn't exist